# Force MS-CHAPv2 VPN connection from Mac

Tags: windows, macos, networking, mac, vpn

If you're trying to connect from a Mac to a Windows Server's VPN (PPTP), accepting only MS-CHAPv2, the client fails with the following error:

`18/6/13 9:06:08.672 AM pppd[10247]: MS-CHAP authentication failed: E=691 Authentication failure`

Proposed solutions ([Post from Macworld](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20050302023720578;), [Post from Apple forum](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/129391?start=0&tstart=0;)) are to disable the `Digitally sign communications (always)` and enable it only `if client agrees` (not tested, since we cannot change the settings on the server).

Often, you don't want to or can't change any setting on the server and thus look for a solution on the client side.

Has anyone found a command line to force the usage of MS-CHAPv2, or, in other words, to preclude the usage of any other authentication method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MacOSX has `pppd` embedded and you can connect via the Terminal. To connect via pppd and have only a subset network routed through the vpn I use the following command line (multiline for readability):

```
sudo pppd 
   remoteaddress *vpn_server_address* 
   pty "*vpn_server_address* --nolaunchpppd" 
   lock 
   user *DOMAIN\\username* 
   password *password* 
   nomppe 
   require-mschap-v2 
   noauth 
   nobsdcomp 
   nodeflate 
   nodetach 
   plugin pptp.ppp 
   noipdefault 
   refuse-pap 
   refuse-eap 
   refuse-chap 
   refuse-mschap 
   plugin /System/Library/SystemConfiguration/PPPController.bundle/Contents/PlugIns/PPPDialogs.ppp  
   logfile /path/to/your/log.log
```

Then, I declare in another terminal the needed route, for example

```
sudo route add -net *distant_local_network* *gateway_ip* *mask*
```

for example

```
sudo route add -net 192.192.0.0 192.192.0.1 255.255.255.0
```

Then all the traffic to the distant network uses the VPN and the rest of Internet is still accessible.

Comment: Thanks!! Just what I needed. I had to change this a little bit to make it work. I added the following options: require-mppe require-mppe-40 require-mppe-128 mppe-stateful

Comment: macos hasn't pppd anymore